# Web Design: Client wants a rotation-based navigation bar

Tags: javascript, css

I don't know if this is possible, but the client is adamant. He wants his navigation bar contents to be aligned along a "Fibonacci Spiral".

This thing:

[image]

I don't even think the CSS3 rotation aspect is functional in any browser currently, and I have no clue if any of the scripting languages would allow me even the faintest of possibilities to create a custom, curving track to force objects to follow instead of the standard (and pretty much only) horizontal and vertical alignment methods. However, I truly do embrace a good challenge. Backing down without an effort is hardly doing a good job.

If any of you know any possibility even of the greatest magnitude in how I might achieve this effect, I would be amazed. THank you for your time! If you think this is truly impossible to achieve in a current web browser, say so!

Comment: What exactly are you aligning on that spiral? Can you do a sketch in an image editor of what you're actually after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting idea anyways. Hope you can make your client happy.
I thought i might chip in with something.
Found a jQuery-plugin that bends text along a curve:
http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/

Perhaps one could make a layout of square divs of diminishing size and specify a curve for each one?

Possible div-layout if you turn it around: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/FibonacciBlocks.svg

The plugin specifies the curving from a radius-value and can curve upwards or downwards. It does not seem to be constructed for tilted curves, but that can perhaps be modified.

EDIT: I experimented a bit with the plugin, and i believe it certainly is possible to achieve the effect you need, albeit one does have to know trigonometry quite well (as far as i can tell) to make it function properly.

Another option, and the easiest way i can think of so far, is to make use of an old classic: Image map!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Just photoshop a nice spiral image however you like and use image mapping to set linkable areas. This can maybe be of interest: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

Comment: Not only did I not think of the image map *facepalm*, but I will definitely give the jQuery-plugin a try. Thank you for enlightening me with that discovery, because while I may be able to quick fix this build with an image map, an image map may not cover a client's needs so easily. Once again, thanks!